# Donor's name is overwritten with name on Paypal account

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I have set up a contribution page using Paypal Express (the one in core). I have added a profile which includes the first and last names of the contact. But when the contact is created, these names are not used, and the contact gets the name from the Paypal account instead. And if the contact already exists, then their name gets overwritten with the name from the Paypal account.

It seems this has been an issue since 2017, or perhaps it is a regression. The following bug report is still open.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20553

Someone asked a question about it here in 2017 but now the code around it has changed and the suggested workaround (which would have meant hacking core anyway) cannot be applied.

[Is there a setting to prevent Paypal Express overwriting contact details with provided Paypal billing details?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21016/is-there-a-setting-to-prevent-paypal-express-overwriting-contact-details-with-pr)

If you are using paypal, are you also experiencing this issue and if so have you found a workaround for it?